# iron of the core of earth

Tags: earth-history, core, solar-terrestrial-physics, reanalysis, planetary-formation

@ralhecman:so why scientists say that the core of the earth is melted Iron, how that happens? if they also say that iron is the result of a dead start, and what about the other planets in the solar system,  are they also have an iron core?